# How to use laravel where clause?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel.
How to convert the following query to Laravel where clause.

```
where category='1' and (shipping_from='1' OR shipping_to='2')
```

Comment: `->where('category', 1)->where(function($q){ $q->where('shipping_from', 1)->orWhere('shipping_to', 2)});` for better view see this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping

Answer (score 5):

You should use nested parameter groupings: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping. Eg:

```
->where('category','1')
->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('shipping_from', '1')
                  ->orWhere('shipping_to', '2');
        })
```

Comment: I am using where like this.
$products = Product::where('')

Comment: So you can code this way:

$products = Product::where('category','1')
->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('shipping_from', '1')
                  ->orWhere('shipping_to', '2');
        })->get();

Comment: yes ,i want to code like  $products = Product::where('')

Answer (score 1):

```
->where('category', 1)
->where(function ($query){
     $query->where('shipping_from', 1)
           ->orWhere('shipping_to', 2);
})
```

Refer to: [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: I am using where like this. $products = Product::where('') –

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation of [parameter-grouping in Laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping)

```
$products = Product::where('category', 1)
            ->where(function ($query){
                $query->where('shipping_from', 1)
                      ->orWhere('shipping_to', 2);
            })->get();
```

Initially laravel thinks `AND` condition in all `where` conditions. until unless you specify `or`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this:-

```
use App\Model;

$data = Model::where('category','1')
                ->where(function ($query) {
                 $query->where('shipping_from', '1')
                 ->orWhere('shipping_to', '2');
                 })->get();
```