# Laravel Query Inside Json Loop

Tags: php, json, laravel

Querying inside a json loop always returns exists even when row does not exist.

Hi I have a Json Object which looks like this

```
{"+888588888":"Person 1", "some_mail@gmail.com":"Person 2"}
```

I am using the following code to check whether the record exists in the table:

```
    // Get The Json From Source
    $json = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    // Loop Through Json And Insert Into Mysql
    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {

        $result = UserInvitesModel::where('mysql_user_id', $mysql_user_id)
            ->where(function ($q) use ($key, $value) {
                $q->where('phone', $key)
                    ->orWhere('email', $key);
            })->get();

        if (empty($result)) {
            echo "does-not-exist ";
        } else {
            echo "exists ";
        }
    }
```

I am always getting exists

Comment: What do you expect as a result? Only one? Multiple?

Comment: result for each key

Comment: Is this to check one user? then why are you using a loop instead of WHERE IN

Comment: yes its for one user

Comment: based my code on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52179609/3904109

Comment: In that case you can do it in one query instead of using a foreach loop. You only user the keys from the array so use `array_keys($json)` and `whereIn()` Side note: consider using good variable names while programming: you've got a variable `$json` that holds an array. That  is confusing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `empty()` on a Collection and that's the problem.

The `->get()` method you use returns a Collection and in order to check if it has at least one element, you have to use `isEmpty()`:

```php
// Get The Json From Source
    $json = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    // Loop Through Json And Insert Into Mysql
    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {

        $result = UserInvitesModel::where('mysql_user_id', $mysql_user_id)
            ->where(function ($q) use ($key, $value) {
                $q->where('phone', $key)
                    ->orWhere('email', $key);
            })->get();

        if ($result->isEmpty()) {
            echo "does-not-exist ";
        } else {
            echo "exists ";
        }
    }
```

`empty()` always returns `false` on Collection:

```php
empty(collect()); // false
collect()->isEmpty(); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

`$result` is never "empty"!! even if no record is returned, it still is an instance of a `Collection::class` with empty array as items.

You should test on `$result->count()` (a method of the collection class)

or improve your code.

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $count = UserInvitesModel::where('mysql_user_id', $mysql_user_id)
        ->where(function ($q) use ($key, $value) {
            $q->where('phone', $key)
                ->orWhere('email', $key);
        })->count(); //return an integer

    if (!$count) {
        echo "does-not-exist ";
    } else {
        echo "exists ";
    }
}
```

if you need the user entity use first instead

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $user = UserInvitesModel::where('mysql_user_id', $mysql_user_id)
        ->where(function ($q) use ($key, $value) {
            $q->where('phone', $key)
                ->orWhere('email', $key);
        })->first(); //returns null or an instance of the model

    if (!$user) {
        echo "does-not-exist ";
    } else {
        echo "exists ";
    }
}
```

Comment: var_dump($user); giving NULL... so used is_null($user) it seems to be working thanks for pushing in that directions